# Get ParticipantResult from TurnBasedMatch

Tags: android, multiplayer, google-play-games

So I have a TurnBasedMatch game. Say there are two players and each has 1 turn. Now its the second players turn. To show that the 2nd player has won I do the following:

```
mywinstatusresult = ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN;
opponentwinstatusresult = ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSS;
myplacing = 1;
opponentplacing = 2;

ParticipantResult myresult = new ParticipantResult(myParticipantId,mywinstatusresult,myplacing );
ParticipantResult opponentresult = new ParticipantResult(getNextParticipantId(),opponentwinstatusresult, opponentplacing);
List<ParticipantResult> reportresult = new ArrayList<ParticipantResult>();
reportresult.add(myresult);
reportresult.add(opponentresult);
                    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(mGoogleApiClient, mMatch.getMatchId(),mTurnData.persist(), reportresult)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                            processResult(result);
                        }
                    });
```

This is an example code! The next player; 1st player who already finished and now gets match results,  will then check what his 'ParticipantResult' is. Only I have trouble doing this, if there even is a way. So what I do is:

```
mMatch.getParticipant(myParticipantId).getResult().getResult()
```

(the first `getResult()` gets the `ParticipantResult` object and the second one gets the result `int` value.)

Which I hoped would return the result of this player, being the value `ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSE`. However, I am getting a NullPointerException. `mMatch` is not null and `myParticipantId` is also not null.

What am I doing wrong here? The workaround I have is to get the Match data and calculate the winner again since the data has the scores saved, only I wanted a cleaner way by getting the previously passed `ParticipantResult`.

Any ideas how this can be achieved or if it actually CAN be achieved?

Comment: Which part of your statement returns null? Is it getParticipant(myParticipantId) or is it getResult()? I have it working in my application so it can indeed be achieved. What is the status of the match when you get the NullPointerException (as reported by mMatch.getStatus())?